# dash window doesnt take input from "indian" text entry (and more..)

Tags: unity-dash, 16.04, ibus, sublime-text, input-language

I have lenovo z50 and recently installed 16.04LTS. I have installed ibus-m17n package for text inputs.

problem 1) "Indian" keyboard layout, part of std XKB package is for inputing hindi text under "settings -> text entry". However, unity dash doesnt take input from it. it simply remains blank. although it takes input from "hi-inscript", part of m17n pkg.

problem 2) situation is somewhat reversed in sublime text 3 latest build. It takes input from "Indian" but writes roman characters when "hi-inscript" is selected.

My default input system is "IBus" as selected in language preferences.

What could be possible solution to fix this?

UPDATE
I checked for bangla, arabic input layout and problem is same. Dash window doesnt register a single input.

Comment: Sounds like bugs. One thing you may want to try is to switch to _fcitx_ in Language Support and install the _fcitx-m17n_ package.

Comment: thanks. I may try fcitx. Any clue on why "Indian" keyboard layout part of XKB package may not able to render a single char in dash? this problem was also present in 14.04.